# Problem with assigning attributes to variations in WooCommerce REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am triying to update a product in WooCommerce with variants and attributes but when I launch the request the variant is created but it is not related to the attribute.

Here is the request:

```
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
'https://wpsiteurl.com',
'consumer_key',
'consumer_secret',
    [
        "version" => "wc/v3",
    ]
);

$data = [
    'regular_price' => '9.00',
    'attributes' => [
        [
            "name" => "test_attribute",
            "option" => "test_term"
        ]
    ]
];

$woocommerce->post("products/"."00000"."/variations",$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please assign the attributes which are already created to the parent product(Variable).And I see that the attributes body needs id & options,you can find them in attributes section. Like below

{"attributes": [
{
"id": 4,
"options": "white"
}
]
}

Comment: I have also tried to create attributes for the product before and after relating them as you say but it has not worked